# Display delivery time in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to display **delivery time** of products along with **IN STOCK** on my magento(1.7) based shopping cart.

For eg: "Delivered in 2-3 business days."

Is there any such option available in Magento community version?

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can implement this is to add a new attribute to the product with all the different delivery options available.

You can then populate this and use the data to update the front end store. Emails etc.

Comment: Custom attribute I can create but It will not be visible with "IN STOCK" option. If a product is "Out of stock" then no delivery time should be there. But if a product is "In stock" then "Delivered in 2-3 business days." should be displayed.

Comment: Hello, You are correct this method wont display based on conditions. You will need to edit template files to add this logic in. It wont be hard your just checking on the product view page template: if ($_product)->getStockItems() > 0 ) { then .... variable names are not correct here but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This will be working for regular products.

```
<?php if ($qtyStock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty()>0):{?>
            <p class="availability in-stock">
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
    <span class="value"><p>Delivery Time:</p>
    <div id="delivery_time"><p>Delivered in 2-3 business days.</p></div></span>
</p>
 <?php } else: { ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock">
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
</p>
            <?php } endif; ?>
```

Comment: kindly give more explanation on how this works for a better understanding